# Pass Number Field As An Array

Tags: php, laravel

I am using a online laravel api doc to execute a program. When i run my code in postman, i get the error "pass number field as an array". But the number field is being already passed as an array field.  What could i be missing below in my code ?  Thanks in advance

```
public function testAPI(Request $request)
    {
        $on_call_back = 'https://learntoday.co.uk/var';
        $id = '*****';
        $url = $on_call_back.'?key='.$id;
        $variables = [
           'number' => ['44234200234,44234242002'],
           'from' => 'world',
           'content' => 'I love to code',
        ];

        $ch = curl_init();
        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($variables));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $result = json_decode($result, TRUE);
        return $data;
        curl_close($ch);
    }
```

When i print out my results, this is what i see

```
 Array
    (
        [number] => Array
            (
                [0] => '44234200234,44234242002'
            )

        [from] => world
        [content] => i love to code
    )
{"status":"error","message":"Pass number field as an array"}
```

Here is the update of how it appears now

```
Array
(
    [recipient] => Array
        (
            [0] => 44234200234
            [1] => 44234242002
        )

   [from] => world
   [content] => i love to code
)
```

Comment: Have you checked the `https://learntoday.co.uk/var` API doc? If the error is thrown by the API, then you have to check the input parameters pattern with them.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
public function testAPI(Request $request)
    {
        $on_call_back = 'https://learntoday.co.uk/var';
        $id = '*****';
        $url = $on_call_back.'?key='.$id;
        $variables = [
           'number' => ['44234200234','44234242002'],
           'from' => 'world',
           'content' => 'I love to code',
        ];

        $ch = curl_init();
        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($variables));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $result = json_decode($result, TRUE);
        return $data;
        curl_close($ch);
    }
```

Comment: i am not able to see the difference with your code and mine

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This :

```
$numbersArray = array("44234200234","44234242002");
$variables = [
    //'number' => ['44234200234','44234242002'],
    'number' => $numbersArray,
    'from' => 'world',
    'content' => 'I love to code',
];
```

Ideally Old solution should work but you can try like this and check it.

Comment: @CodeNewbie Instead of passing in a string as comma separeted you need to pass as an array. like 2 elements in the square brackets " 'number' => ['44234200234','44234242002'], "

Answer (score 0):

You should try passing numbers on different indexes of array:

```
$variables = [
   'number' => ['44234200234','44234242002'],
   'from' => 'world',
   'content' => 'I love to code',
];
```

Currently you are passing both numbers separated with , on 0 index.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your array as 1 string. To achieve with this (incorrect) approach, you would need to seperate the strings by a comma, and then convert each string to an integer.

```
  'number' => ['44234200234,44234242002,1,2,3,4'], // this is ONE string

  'number' => ['1', '2', '3', '4'] // this is many strings
```

What you want to do is pass an array of integers

```
numbers => [1, 2, 3]
```

Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use serialize function:

```
$on_call_back = 'https://learntoday.co.uk/var';
$id = '*****';
$url = $on_call_back.'?key='.$id;
$variables = [
     'number' => serialize(['44234200234','44234242002']),
     'from' => 'world',
     'content' => 'I love to code',
];
```